Error: "Missing classes detected while running R8." with AdMob 23.4.0
After upgrading AdMob from 23.3.0 to 23.4.0  I get the following errors during Release build:

Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing
classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in [My
project folder]/build/outputs/mapping/release/missing_rules.txt.

And

Missing class
android.media.LoudnessCodecController$OnLoudnessCodecUpdateListener
(referenced from: void
com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsp.zzd(int) and 1 other context) 
Missing class android.media.LoudnessCodecController (referenced from:
android.media.LoudnessCodecController
com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzsp.zzb and 4 other contexts)

The following issue was reported to Google:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/NXPiDjbT2QE/m/PKKmI-38AwAJ
Any workaround except downgrading to AdMob 23.3.0?
How to reproduce the issue in a new, clean project:

Create a new Android project (all default settings).
In the build.gradle.kts of the app module:

Section: android => buildTypes => release, set isMinifyEnabled = true.
Section: dependencies, add api("com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:23.4.0")


Set the build type in the Build Variants to Release.
From the main menu - Build => Build App Bundle(s)/APK(s) => Build Bundle(s).

The build will fail with the same error.
Update: Upgrading to AdMob 23.5.0 cause the same issue.

Did you tried to update proguard-rules.pro as the error message says? You can find it [My project folder]/build/outputs/mapping/release/missing_rules.txt, copy content of missing_rules.txt and put it into proguard-rules.pro.

@MiroslavHýbler This is not the problem (the updated rules are taken using getDefaultProguardFile() method).

AdMob 23.4.0 uses android.media.LoudnessCodecController which was added to Android only in SDK 35.
The documentation of AdMob 23.1.0 clearly states: Requires a minimum compileSdkVersion of 34, however version 23.4.0 is missing the following: Requires a minimum compileSdkVersion of 35.
There are 3 solutions:

Update compileSdkVersion to 35.
Continue using AdMob 23.3.0 until the project is ready for Android SDK 35.
Use @Miroslav solution to add rules to ProGuard. It's probably safe since those classes were added only in Android SDK 35.


I followed the steps and the problem is that you didn't included missing_rules.txt as the error message says, getDefaultProguardFile() will not solve the problem for you.
After running release build i got same error leading me to rules:

In my case missing_rules.txt content was:
# Please add these rules to your existing keep rules in order to suppress warnings.
# This is generated automatically by the Android Gradle plugin.
-dontwarn android.media.LoudnessCodecController$OnLoudnessCodecUpdateListener
-dontwarn android.media.LoudnessCodecController

Now this is my case, your rules will be located at [app]/build/outputs/mapping/release/missing_rules.txt. After copy&paste these rules into app's proguard-rules.pro release build will be sucessful.
The cause is probably that firebase-ads are referencing some classes which are not included in the sources (can be reflection to some google play SDK). -dontwarn is used to suppress warnings to missing sources.
As explained here getDefaultProguardFile() gets android's default rules and combine them with your rules from proguard-rules.pro it's not adding missing rules of your module automatically.

As you said, this will suppress the error messages, if those classes are required by AdMob SDK it will create a problem. There's another option to add rules to prevent those classes from being removed. I still prefer to rollback to 23.3.0 and wait for a fix.

@sagis i am really not getting your point. It will not create problem because the sources are part of play services or Android sdk. You cant provide them to R8  so you need to dontwarn them. All else I can suggest is double check documentation on how proguard works.

The problem is that the new classes added in Android SDK 35. Compiling with Android 34 will generate this error. Your solution is probably safe, but I still prefer trying to compile with Android SDK 35 or wait until all my app's dependencies will be ready for it.

Agree with @sagis, dontwarn approach whenever there is a missing class is a double edge sword and should be used wisely.

from above answer 1 correction add $*  to solve this issue else unresolved class name issue will be happened
-dontwarn android.media.LoudnessCodecController$OnLoudnessCodecUpdateListener$*
-dontwarn android.media.LoudnessCodecController$*

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I've encountered this issue on my expo react native project. By adding the missing classes to the property 'extraProguardRules' on app.json the issue was solved.
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "android": {
        "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true,
        "extraProguardRules": "-keep public class com.horcrux.svg.** {*;}\n-dontwarn android.media.LoudnessCodecController$OnLoudnessCodecUpdateListener\n-dontwarn android.media.LoudnessCodecController",
        "allowBackup": false
      }
    }
  ],

